# .NET Core API action with generics and AutoMapper

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, refactoring, automapper

I am building an ASP.NET Core API. I have an action that I want to be essentially identical across a set of controllers. So, I created the `EntityController` that those controllers inherit from as below.

Note: The ellipsis used in both classes below represent many more actions and their related services following the same pattern omitted for simplicity.

```
public class EntityController : BaseController
{
    protected readonly SeedService SeedService;

    protected EntityController(IMemoryCache memoryCache, SeedService seedService) : base(memoryCache)
    {
        SeedService = seedService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Seed()
    {
        var controllerName = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        return await GetSeed(controllerName);
    }

    private async Task<IActionResult> GetSeed(string controllerName)
    {
        switch (controllerName)
        {
            case "lists":
                return await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(CacheKeys.Entry, async entry =>
                {
                    entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
                    return Json(await SeedService.GetAllFilterLists());
                });
            case "languages":
                return await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(CacheKeys.Entry, async entry =>
                {
                    entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
                    return Json(await SeedService.GetAllLanguages());
                });
            ...
            default:
                return await Task.FromResult(NotFound());
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the service methods that these actions call:

```
public class SeedService
{
    private readonly FilterListsDbContext filterListsDbContext;

    public SeedService(FilterListsDbContext filterListsDbContext)
    {
        this.filterListsDbContext = filterListsDbContext;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<FilterListSeedDto>> GetAllFilterLists()
    {
        return await filterListsDbContext.Set<FilterList>().ProjectTo<FilterListSeedDto>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<LanguageSeedDto>> GetAllLanguages()
    {
        return await filterListsDbContext.Set<Language>().ProjectTo<LanguageSeedDto>().ToListAsync();
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I use generics (or alternative) to reduce this copy/paste duplication? I tried using something like a `Dictionary<string, Type>` to lookup the `Type` dynamically from the controller name, but I am not sure how the resulting `GetAll<T>()` method in `SeedService` would look? Below doesn't work because the method depends on the types of both the entity and DTO models for the AutoMapper projection.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll<T>()
{
    return await filterListsDbContext.Set<T>().ProjectTo<T>().ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `Task<IEnumerable<TMapped>> GetAll<TEntity, TMapped> => .Set<TEntity>().ProjectTo<TMapped>()`?

Comment: Oh, nice, that's slick! Thanks! That drastically simplifies my service class. Can you think of a way to eliminate the switch statement in the controller? I'd have to lookup the mapping types dynamically somehow.

Comment: I love seeing red. :) https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/commit/45e470f8316e821dd8c19b3e62cbf918c7e96f23

Comment: I can imagine a `Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>` that mapped a controller's name to an entity/mapped name, but not sure if filling that would actually be "cleaner" than using a switch as you already do

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's kind of where my mind is going. Maybe it would be better to put individual `GetSeed()` methods in their respective controllers rather than the big switch in the parent controller? I'm reading "Clean Code" right now and probably over-analyzing everything. Ha! Thanks for your help, @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: If you did that, you could make each controller inherit a base controller/class that had a `TEntity, TMapped` class-level generic and put `GetAll` there

Comment: Rather than using a switch, you could use an adapter pattern. Basically, you'd have something like an `ISeed` interface, with a `Seed` method. Then, you can inject different implementations of `ISeed` based on the scenario. All the controller knows is that that it has an `ISeed` that it needs to call `Seed` on. Everything else is abstracted into your implementation(s).

Comment: thanks, @ChrisPratt . I might give that a shot. if I am understanding correctly, though, that wouldn't really cut down on duplication. it would just break up the switch into different seed implementations.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , if you wanted to convert your first comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it to give you rep. That was really the answer I was seeking. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily remove all that boilerplate code into a single generic method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetAll<TEntry, TResult>() where TEntry : class
{
    return await filterListsDbContext.Set<TEntry>()
        .ProjectTo<TResult>()
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Since you are returning an `IEnumerable`, you may want to change to `.ToArrayAsync()`. Also, since you are projecting to non-entities, and hence changes won't be picked up by the context, you could go further and add `.AsNoTracking()` to avoid adding the entities to the context:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetAll<TEntry, TResult>() where TEntry : class
{
    return await filterListsDbContext.Set<TEntry>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ProjectTo<TResult>()
        .ToArrayAsync();
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you could put that in a base controller and do something like this:

```
public class BaseController<TEntity, TViewModel>
{    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TViewModel>> GetAll()
    {
        return await filterListsDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ProjectTo<TViewModel>()
            .ToArrayAsync();
    }
}

public class LanguageController : BaseController<Language, LanguageSeedDto>
{
    (in some action)
    var data = await GetAll();
}
```